# Why is my auth computed property not updating my DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

I made a nuxt frontend with authentication features based on [the nuxt-apollo module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module). My layout will change depending on whether the user is logged in or not. To do so, I have a simple `v-if=isAuthenticated` in my layout. Here is the code below:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <!-- authenticated user -->
    <template v-if="isAuthenticated">
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-fade-transition mode="out-in">
                <nuxt />
              </v-fade-transition>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </template>
    <!-- unauthenticated user -->
    <template v-else>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>  
          <v-fade-transition mode="out-in">
            <nuxt />
          </v-fade-transition>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </template>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  computed: {
    isAuthenticated() {
      return !!this.$apolloHelpers.getToken();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

`!!this.$apolloHelpers.getToken()` is what is used in [the middleware from the example auth app](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/tree/master/test/fixture) to allow or deny authenticated routes.

**The problem:** When the user logs in and that the token is set, the computed property is not re-executed and the layout is not updated. It renders correctly if I refresh the page however.

I previously used the [nuxt auth module](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/), and it was working fine when using their helper `v-if="$auth.loggedIn"` to do the switch.

As I am quite new to Vue, I wondered if I am missing the obvious or if it is not how I should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Vue will **only** update your computed property value **when one of its dependencies change**.
In your case, `$apolloHelpers.getToken()` will not be updated when you call `$apolloHelpers.onLogin()`. The `getToken` function will still have the same reference, the only thing that will change is your **Apollo authentication cookie**.

One of the options you have is to use a package like [vue-reactive-cookie](https://github.com/tabbies/vue-reactive-cookie) to watch your cookie and make sure your local variable is always up-to-date.
You could also use Vuex to keep a global variable and update it whenever you call `$apolloHelpers.onLogin()` or `$apolloHelpers.onLogout()`, and watch it inside your components to keep a local variable updated.